# Why is the user profile different here?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In most of my sub-exchanges, when I look at my profile the leftmost box has a graph of your rep changes.

That box does not appear here in retro, instead there is a simpler box.

Any reason why? I like the graph. I guess this is bug-like?

**UPDATE:** added images...

Here is the box in my SO account:

[image]

Here it is in Retro:

[image]

Comment: Might be about configuration. @wizzwizz4 or Chenmunka might be able to tell more.

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot? What do you mean by a simpler box? Is it a "congratulation on a new privilege" message, or just "a reputation & next privilege"? If it's the former, you just need to click "track next". If it's the latter, it might the mobile version which can be switched on the footer (mobile <-> full site)

Answer (score 2):

That's your meta profile. Meta sites don't show the rep graph. Your main Retrocomputing graph should be normal.

Comment: This is true.  On meta sites the reputation graph isn't shown because you don't earn any reputation on meta sites.  The graph is shown where the reputation is earnt.

Comment: I have the same display in my main retro screen too.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Are you sure? [Here's a link to it](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4196/maury-markowitz). It's confusing because your picture shows the meta CSS.